# Using google api SheetsService batchupdate InsertDimension request does not preserve formatting

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am using batchupdate to insert new rows into an existing spreadsheet. My understanding, which may be wrong, is by using inheritFromBefore => true|false , that the formatting of the inserted dimension row would be the same as the the row before or after depending on whether it is set to try or not. This should inherit colours, validation etc ? However this isn't the case and the new row is just an unformatted row.

this is an example of the request that I am using :

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertDimension": {
        "inheritFromBefore": false,
        "range": {
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 1,
          "sheetId": 0,
          "endIndex": 2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updateCells": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 2
        },
        "fields": "*",
        "rows": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "some data"
                }
              },
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "more data"
                }
              },
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "0879767"
                }
              },
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "test@gmail.com"
                }
              },
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "numberFormat": {
                    "pattern": "dd-mm-yyyy",
                    "type": "DATE"
                  }
                },
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "numberValue": 1697719239
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Perhaps my expectation is wrong but this is what is says in the documentation:

*For example, if row index 0 has red background and row index 1 has a green background, then inserting 2 rows at index 1 can inherit either the green or red background. If inheritFromBefore is true, the two new rows will be red (because the row before the insertion point was red), whereas if inheritFromBefore is false, the two new rows will be green (because the row after the insertion point was green).*

[https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest]

Many thanks

Comment: Figured this one out the issue is with updateCells fields": "*" ; Can't say I understand why but if you want to meet the formatting that is already in place you need to be more explicit so in my case this worked:

"fields": "userEnteredValue.stringValue,userEnteredValue.numberValue,userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"